# com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadRequest: {"error": "OAuth 2 \"Authorization\" header is not well-formed."}

Tags: dropbox-api

I am getting  following exception on uploading file to dropbox using java api.

```
com.dropbox.core.DbxException$BadRequest: {"error": "OAuth 2 \"Authorization\" header is not well-formed."}
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.unexpectedStatus(DbxRequestUtil.java:207)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$SingleUploader$1.handle(DbxClient.java:765)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$SingleUploader$1.handle(DbxClient.java:761)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestUtil.finishResponse(DbxRequestUtil.java:279)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient$SingleUploader.finish(DbxClient.java:761)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.finishUploadFile(DbxClient.java:629)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.uploadFile(DbxClient.java:562)
    at com.dropbox.core.DbxClient.uploadFile(DbxClient.java:514)
```

following is my code

```
public DbxClient authDropbox(String authAccessToken)throws IOException, DbxException {
    DbxRequestConfig dbxRequestConfig = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaDropboxTutorial/1.0", Locale.getDefault().toString());
    dbxClient = new DbxClient(dbxRequestConfig, authAccessToken);
    return dbxClient;
}
public String uploadToDropbox(String filePath,String fileName,String folderName,DbxClient dbxClient) throws DbxException,IOException {
        String sharedUrl;
        File inputFile = new File(filePath);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
        dbxClient.uploadFile("/"+folderName+"/"+ fileName,DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), fis);
        sharedUrl = dbxClient.createShareableUrl("/"+folderName +"/"+fileName);         
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }       
    return sharedUrl;
}
```

file upload code

Answer (score 0):

The error 'OAuth 2 "Authorization" header is not well-formed.' indicates that the header that contains the OAuth 2 access token doesn't match the pattern expected for the header.

The header is built for you by the SDK using the `accessToken` parameter you supply to [the `DbxClient` constructor](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.8.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#DbxClient(com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig,%20java.lang.String)), which in your case is your `authAccessToken` variable.

That likely means that the value of your `authAccessToken` isn't a valid access token, and whatever string it does contain is causing the header to not match the pattern. For example, it might contain whitespace, which could cause this.

To fix this, you should inspect the value of your `authAccessToken` and see what's in it and why it's malformed, and prevent that from happening again in the future.